# Image button formatting

Tags: android, image, button, center

[image]

Above is my desired designed to build on my activity, in which I want to place the image of button just left to button text and want this on centered.

can anyone tell me how to make this thing???

Here is the code to divide buttons width to 50% 50%

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_settings"
            android:text="@string/search" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3" 
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_separator" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_settings"
            android:text="@string/profile" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: To be clear you want to put the icon in the center and not to the left?

Answer (score 1):

To place the image as in your screenshot, use [`drawableStart`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_drawableStart) instead of `drawableLeft`.

Answer (score 0):

> You can also use this code for imageButtons.`

```
<ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/backicon" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:background="@drawable/backicondn"></ImageButton>
```

> Change image by programe

`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageButton imageButton;
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
        imageButton.setImageBitmap(bm);

    }`
[image]